# Trying to do a lag over multiple items

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I am working on the Nasa Mission Launch dataset I found and I am trying to use lag to see the difference in money spent over the years in a decade (How much it goes up or down YOY).  When I ran the lag it returned an error: Budget_lag must be size 1 not 10.  I have the years grouped by decades.  I am currently working on the sixties.

Should I do this as a loop so it goes through each year?

Here is my code:

```
sixties_budget %>% 
  group_by(sixties_budget$Budget) %>%
  mutate(Budget_lag = lag(sixties_budget$Budget))
  diff =   Budget - Budget_lag %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(percentage = diff/Budget_lag)
```

The error I got:

```
Error in `mutate()`:`
ℹ In argument: `Budget_lag =
  lag(sixties_budget$Budget)
ℹ In group 1: `sixties_budget$Budget = 3622571944
Caused by error:`
! Budget_lag` must be size 1, not 10.`
```

Comment: When using `dplyr`, you can refer to a variable in a data frame directly, since the name of the data frame is piped in. So you can just call `Budget` and not `sixties_budget$Budget`. Also the line starting with `diff` will result in an error, as it needs to be within `mutate()` (and you are missing a pipe right before).

Comment: More strongly than "you **can** just call `Budget` and not `sixties_budget$Budget`", you **must**--that is the source of your error. `sixties_budget` is not a grouped data frame, so `sixties_budget$Budget` is the entire ungrouped column. When you pipe it in and then `group_by` you have an unnamed grouped version of the data that `mutate` looks within when you use column names like `Budget`. But when you specify `sixties_budget$Budget` you are overriding that behavior, forcing `mutate` to look in the original ungrouped data, hence the error.

Comment: Though, upon closer reading, `group_by(Budget)` is a bad idea. That will only group rows together if the budget is unchanged, and if there is no change in budget then calculating the difference is pointless. There should be no need for grouping at all for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have your data to test, but following the advice in comments I think this should work:

```
sixties_budget %>% 
  mutate(
    Budget_lag = lag(Budget)
    diff =   Budget - Budget_lag,
    percentage = diff / Budget_lag
  ) %>%
  na.omit()
```